# MySQL: Copy related records from other tables after copying "parent" record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In my app, I have a stored procedure that copies rows based on a time interval.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (
    <field list>
) 
SELECT 
<field list>,
CASE rwo_frequency
WHEN 2 then DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHEN <other values for rwo_frequency>
END AS start_date,
FROM my_table
WHERE start_date = CASE rwo_frequency
WHEN 2 then DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
WHEN <other values for rwo_frequency>
END
AND is_recurring = 1;
```

After those rows are copied, I also need to copy their related records in another table. For example, `my_table` has a related table called `my_relations` with the following structure:

```
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wa_id            | int(11)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| related_doc_id   | int(11)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| is_parent        | int(5)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| created          | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_user_id  | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| modified         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_user_id | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| deleted_record   | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| deleted_user_id  | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted          | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this table, `wa_id` is the foreign key that points to `my_table`. There is a record in `my_relations` with the following values:

```
select id, wa_id, related_doc_id from my_relations;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | wa_id | related_doc_id |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  1 |     1 |            286 |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

Suppose I copy record ID 1 in `my_table` and it gets an ID of 10. What I need is to be able to copy the record shown above in `my_relations`, but with `wa_id = 10`. I've already taken a stab at it:

```
INSERT INTO my_relations (
wa_id,
related_doc_id,
created,
created_user_id
)
SELECT
wa.id,
related_doc_id,
NOW() AS created,
wa.resp_engineer_id AS created_user_id
FROM my_table wa
LEFT JOIN my_relations d
ON wa.id = d.wa_id
WHERE wa.created = CURDATE()
AND wa.is_recurring = 1;
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the value of `related_doc_id` into my new record. It always comes up NULL after the record is inserted. `wa_id`, however, is correct. I thought the join would take care of it, but apparently not. How can I copy this row so that my resultset is like this after the copy?

```
select id, wa_id, related_doc_id from my_relations;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | wa_id | related_doc_id |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  1 |     1 |            286 |
|  2 |    10 |            286 |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

EDIT: I was asked about the relationships among the tables. `my_relations` is a linking table between `my_table` and another table called `docs`. `wa_id` is the foreign key pointing to `my_table`, and `related_doc_id` is the foreign key pointing to `docs`. This relationship must be duplicated when its `my_table` record is copied. The relationship between the old ID and the new is in a column called `copied_wo` in `my_table`. When row 1 gets copied and gets an ID of 10, `copied_wo`in row 10 gets updated with a value of 1, showing that row 10 was copied from it.

Comment: Where is the relationship between old ID 1 and new ID 10 stored?

Comment: You need this mapping saved somewhere so you can link the related documents to the new ID.

Comment: @Barmar: See my edit above where I explain the relationships among the tables and where the relationship between ID 1 and ID 10 is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `copied_wo` column to join `my_table` with itself so you can get `related_doc_id` from the `my_relations` row linked to the original row in `my_table`.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_relations (wa_id, related_doc_id, created, created_user_id)
SELECT wa1.id, d.related_doc_id, NOW(), wa1.resp_engineer_id
FROM my_table wa1  -- new row
JOIN my_table wa2 ON wa1.copied_wo = wa2.id  -- original row it was copied from
LEFT JOIN my_relations AS d ON wa2.id = d.wa_id  -- related row of original
WHERE wa1.created = CURDATE() AND wa1.is_recurring = 1;
```